# jQuery to get user groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, groups, jsom

I would like to redirect based on a users group membership.  First get the users groups and then have a switch statement to redirect based on 1 of 5 groups.

Below is my code I get to alert that says I get this far then nothing happens in UI

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Wait until SP.JS has loaded before calling getWebUserData 
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebUserData, "sp.js");
});

var context = null; 
var web = null; 
var currentUser = null;
var userGroups = null;
var displayGroups = null;

function getWebUserData() {

    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();   // Get the current user 
    web = context.get_web();                        // Get the current web    
    currentUser = web.get_currentUser();            // Get the current user 
    context.load(currentUser);                      // Load the current user 

    userGroups = currentUser.get_groups();
    context.load(userGroups);

    alert('I get this far then nothing!');

    var groupsEnumerator = userGroups.getEnumerator();
    alert('var groupsEnumerator ');

    while (groupsEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var group = groupsEnumerator.get_current();
        displayGroups += group.get_title() + ' \n ';
    }
    context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccessMethod, onFailureMethod);
}

function onSuccessMethod() {
    alert(displayGroups);
    alert('User name:' + currentUser.get_title() + '\n Login Name:' + currentUser.get_loginName());

}

function onFailureMethod(sender, args) {

    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to operate with groups before actually receiving data from the server.

The code which executes the query to the server and fetches your group is `context.executeQueryAsync`.

So you need to put your logic around groups iteration inside `onSuccessMethod` - when the groups data received:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Wait until SP.JS has loaded before calling getWebUserData 
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebUserData, "sp.js");
});

var context = null; 
var web = null; 
var currentUser = null;
var userGroups = null;
var displayGroups = null;

function getWebUserData() {

    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();   // Get the current user 
    web = context.get_web();                        // Get the current web    
    currentUser = web.get_currentUser();            // Get the current user 
    context.load(currentUser);                      // Load the current user 

    userGroups = currentUser.get_groups();
    context.load(userGroups);

    alert('I get this far then nothing!');


    context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccessMethod, onFailureMethod);
}

function onSuccessMethod() {
    var groupsEnumerator = userGroups.getEnumerator();
    alert('var groupsEnumerator ');

    while (groupsEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var group = groupsEnumerator.get_current();
        displayGroups += group.get_title() + ' \n ';
    }
    alert(displayGroups);
    alert('User name:' + currentUser.get_title() + '\n Login Name:' + currentUser.get_loginName());

}

function onFailureMethod(sender, args) {

    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

}
```

Comment: Will this find security groups? I created a security group and added myself but when the alert(displayGroups) shows the value is null.  I am also site admin.  Thanks!

Comment: Nope, it only returns SharePoint groups user belongs to.

Comment: Is there away to get security groups? or can i add sharepoint groups?

Comment: @TonyDanza if the answer is resolved your particular issue, please don't forget to mark an answer as Accepted.

Comment: From javascript it's not possible to get security groups.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JQuery library SPServices (https://spservices.codeplex.com/) to test for a user's group membership. I've used this code several times to check for group membership, then you can put in your switch statement or redirect in depending on the group the person is in.

Hope this helps.

```
<script src="http://yourpath/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        isGroupMember("YOUR_GROUP_NAME", function(result) {
            if (result) {
                alert("is member");
            } else {
                alert("Is not member");
            }
        });


        function isGroupMember(groupName, callback) {
            $().SPServices({
                operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
                userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
                async: true,
                completefunc: function(xData, Status) {

                    callback(!!($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='" + groupName + "']").length)); /* returns bool */
                }
            });
        };

    });
</script>
```